Python Multiprocessing: when I launch many processes on a huge pandas data frame, the program gets stuck
I am trying to gain execution time with python's multiprocessing library (pool_starmap) on a code that executes the same task in parallel, on the same Pandas DataFrame, but with different call arguments.
When I execute this code on a small portion of the data frame and with 10 jobs, everything works just fine. However when I put the whole 100 000 000 lines dataset with 63 jobs (using a cluster computer with 64 CPU cores for this), the code just... freezes. It is running, but not doing anything (I know it because, once every 10 000 task, the code is supposed to print that it is alive).
I have searched and found similar issues on the internet, but none of the answers applied to my specific case, so here I am.
Minimal Example
I have made a minimal, self-sustaining example to reproduce this problem.
Let's say to simplify that my data frame has 2 columns; the 1st one being "stores", the other is "price". I want to recover the mean_price for each store.
Of course in this specific problem one would just groupBy the dataframe on stores and aggregate over the price but this is a simplification; let's assume that the task can only be done one store at a time (this is my case). Here's what a minimal example looks like:
#minimal example
#changes according to SIGHUP and Frank Yellin

import time
import pandas as pd
import random as rd
import multiprocessing as mp

import psutil #RAM usage

def create_datafile(nrows):
    """
    create a random pandas dataframe file
    To visualize this rather simple example,
    let's say that we are looking at a pool of 0.1*nrows products across different stores,
    that can have different values of the attribute "price"
    (in the list "stores").
    """
    
    price = [rd.randint(0,300) for i in range(nrows)]
    stores = [i%(0.1*nrows) for i in range(nrows)]

    data=zip(stores,price)
 
    return pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["stores", "price"])

            
def task(store):
    global data
    """
    the task we want to accomplish: compute mean price
    for each store in the dataframe.
    """

    if rd.randint(1,10000)==1:
        print('I am alive!')

    product_df = data.groupby('stores', as_index = False).agg(mean_price = ("price", 'mean'))

    selected_store = product_df[product_df['stores'] == store] #select the mean for a given store

    return (store, selected_store['mean_price'])

def pinit(_df):
    global data 
    data = _df

def get_ram_usage_pct(): 
    #source: https://www.pragmaticlinux.com/2020/12/monitor-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python-with-psutil/
    """
    Obtains the system's current RAM usage.
    :returns: System RAM usage as a percentage.
    :rtype: float
    """
    return psutil.virtual_memory().percent


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ##
    nrows=100000000
    nb_jobs= 63

    print('Creating data...')
    df = create_datafile(nrows)
    print('Data created.')

    print('RAM usage after data creation is {} %'.format(get_ram_usage_pct()))


    stores_list = [i%(0.1*nrows) for i in range(nrows)]

    dic_mean={}
    #launch multiprocessing tasks with starmap
    tic=time.time()
    print(f'Max number of jobs: {mp.cpu_count() - 1}')
    print(f'Running: {min(nb_jobs, mp.cpu_count() - 1)} jobs...')
    with mp.Pool(initializer=pinit, initargs=(df,), processes=min(nb_jobs, mp.cpu_count() - 1)) as pool:
        for store,result in pool.map_async(task, stores_list).get():
            dic_mean[store] = result[store]
    toc=time.time()
    print(f'Processed data in {round((toc-tic)/60,1)} minutes (rounded to 0.1).') 

    #print(dic_mean)
    #dic_means now contains all the means computed by each program.

I am using Python 3.9.2.
If you launch this code with:

nrows = 10000 and nb_jobs = 10, you should not encounter any problem.
however with nrows=100000000 and nb_jobs=63, the issue I mentionned should occur.

I am rather new to Python Multiprocessing, so any hint would be welcome ! Thanks in advance.

Are you sure thd system is not running out of memory? Please check it in top or Task Manager.

good question. Yes, I have checked and memory does not appear to be the problem. I modified the code from my question to add a RAM test showing the percentage of RAM being used: the dataset only uses 2% of RAM on the computer cluster I am using. Maybe something happens when the processes are created...

Ok, so thanks to @SIGHUP and @Frank Yellin, I was able to find the issue, so I will share it here if anyone encounters a similar issue.
Python seems unable to print anything when there are too many concurrent processes running.
The solution, to check if your program is alive, is to make it write into a .txt file, for example. Once there are too many processes, print statements will NOT appear in the Python console.
I don't know if the print statements freeze the entire program or if it continues running. However I would suggest removing any print statement to avoid any surprise.
Here is a way to make the code from my example work without hassle (beware, 1 000 000 rows or more will take a long time):
#minimal example
#changes according to SIGHUP and Frank Yellin

import time
import pandas as pd
import random as rd
import multiprocessing as mp

import psutil #RAM usage

import sys

def create_datafile(nrows):
    """
    create a random pandas dataframe file
    To visualize this rather simple example,
    let's say that we are looking at a pool of 0.1*nrows products across different stores,
    that can have different values of the attribute "price"
    (in the list "stores").
    """
    
    price = [rd.randint(0,300) for i in range(nrows)]
    stores = [i%(0.1*nrows) for i in range(nrows)]

    data=zip(stores,price)
 
    return pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["stores", "price"])

            
def task(store):
    global data
    global alive_file
    """
    the task we want to accomplish: compute mean price
    for each store in the dataframe.
    """

    #print('I am alive!',flush=True) DO NOT put a print statement

    with open(alive_file, 'a') as f:
        f.write("I am alive !")

    product_df = data.groupby('stores', as_index = False).agg(mean_price = ("price", 'mean'))

    selected_store = product_df[product_df['stores'] == store] #select the mean for a given store

    return (store, selected_store['mean_price'])

def pinit(_df, _alive_file):
    global data 
    global alive_file
    data = _df
    alive_file = _alive_file

def get_ram_usage_pct(): #source: https://www.pragmaticlinux.com/2020/12/monitor-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python-with-psutil/
    """
    Obtains the system's current RAM usage.
    :returns: System RAM usage as a percentage.
    :rtype: float
    """
    return psutil.virtual_memory().percent


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ##
    nrows= int(sys.argv[1]) #number of rows in dataframe
    nb_jobs= int(sys.argv[2]) #number of jobs


    print('Creating data...')
    tic=time.time()
    df = create_datafile(nrows)
    toc=time.time()
    print(f'Data created. Took {round((toc-tic)/60,1)} minutes (rounded to 0.1)')

    print('RAM usage after data creation is {} %'.format(get_ram_usage_pct()))

    #print(data_df)

    #create parameters for multiprocessing task
    stores_list = [(i % (0.1 * nrows),) for i in range(nrows)]
    #dics_stores=[{} for _ in stores_list]
    #parameters = [(df, stores_list[i]) for i in range(nrows)]

    dic_mean={}
    #launch multiprocessing tasks with starmaps
    tic=time.time()
    print(f'Max number of jobs: {mp.cpu_count() - 1}')
    print(f'Running: {min(nb_jobs, mp.cpu_count() - 1)} jobs...')
    with mp.Pool(initializer=pinit, initargs=(df,"alive.txt",), processes=min(nb_jobs, mp.cpu_count() - 1)) as pool:
        for store,result in pool.starmap_async(task, stores_list).get():
            dic_mean[store] = result[store]
    toc=time.time()
    print(f'Processed data in {round((toc-tic)/60,1)} minutes (rounded to 0.1).') 

    #print(dic_mean)
    #dic_means now contains all the means computed by each program.

Thank you to everyone who took the time to examine my issue and made my code better, helping me identify the true issue.

You are having every task return back a dictionary which is growing larger and larger as you process more and more rows.  That's not what you want to do.
def task(data, store):
   .....
   return store, <result>

and then:
<change parameters not to include the dict>

with pool as multiprocessing.pool():
    for store, result in pool.startmap(task, parameters)
        put results into dictionary here.


good point, thanks for the tip. I have modified the code accordingly; it does not solve the issue but I guess it is a good start!

You can eliminate some pickling by using a Pool initializer.
Even so, 100m rows in your DataFrame is going to take some serious CPU time.
Here's a revision of your implementation that demonstrates the technique:
import pandas as pd
import random as rd
import multiprocessing as mp


def create_datafile(nrows):
    price = [rd.randint(0, 300) for i in range(nrows)]
    stores = [i % (0.1 * nrows) for i in range(nrows)]
    return pd.DataFrame(zip(stores, price), columns=["stores", "price"])


def task(store):
    global data 
    product_df = data.groupby('stores', as_index = False).agg(mean_price = ("price", 'mean'))
    selected_store = product_df[product_df['stores'] == store]
    return {store: selected_store['mean_price']}

def pinit(_df):
    global data 
    data = _df

def main():
    nrows = 1_000_000
    df = create_datafile(nrows)
    stores_list = [(i % (0.1 * nrows),) for i in range(nrows)]
    dic_mean = {}
    with mp.Pool(initializer=pinit, initargs=(df,)) as pool:
        for result in pool.starmap_async(task, stores_list).get():
            dic_mean.update(result)
    #print(dic_mean)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


thanks, I have declared the data variables as global, this is a good idea. Indeed 100m is a lot but the code should at least periodically print "I am alive!". I have submitted the changes to the code in my question; it is still not working with this modification.
PS: in your answer, you still use pool.starmap but given there is only one arg, it is supposed to by pool_map.

@Lyreck Note the difference in the way stores_list is constructed in main() This allows us to use starmap even though, as you rightly point out, it's not really necessary in this case. map_async would make more sense for single parameters. Declaring your dataframe as a global is not a great idea. Use the Pool initializer instead. Also, your "I'm alive" mechanism is flawed. There is approximately a 1 in 10,000 chance of this being printed. That's different to every 10,000 invocations

understood. I used the Pool initializer as you indicated (see updated code in my question). I also removed the "1 in 10,000 chance" in my tests and nothing shows up (this condition was just a way to avoid flooding the console with prints when the code works; the problem remains that nothing happens once the jobs are created...)

@Lyreck I've done some timings. On my machine (Apple Silicon M2), if nrows==1_000_000 the groupby() function takes 0.022s and therefore would occupy ~6hrs of CPU time. Increasing nrows to 100m is likely take much longer than you'd normally be prepared to wait

@Lyreck I suggest you set nrows==100_000_000 then time the call to create_datafile()

Yes I agree the code should take several CPU hours to execute.
For nrows=100_000_000 the datafile is created in 2.3 minutes (config:2 CPUs Intel Xeon E5-2650 v4, 12 cores/CPU, 128GB RAM) .
I have launched two tests (nrows=100_000_000 and nrows=10_000_000) for 24hours of runtime. For the moment no "I am alive" is printed, I'll wait until the runtime is over and get back to you.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
